# firewalld --permanent not working after service reload

Tags: configuration, firewalld

I have a fedora firewall that has two interfaces. When I try to do `firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=external --add-interface=eno1` and then reload firewalld with `firewall-cmd --reload`, the interface does not seem to be added. `firewall-cmd --get-active-zones` shows both eno1 and eno2 sitting in the public, which is the default, zone. There is a file in `/etc/firewalld/zones/external.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<zone>
  <short>External</short>
  <description>For use on external networks. You do not trust the other computers on networks to not harm
 your computer. Only selected incoming connections are accepted.</description>
  <interface name="eno1"/>
  <service name="ssh"/>
  <masquerade/>
</zone>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that if you are using NetworkManager (you almost certainly are) then [the network configuration for each interface will override the firewalld configuration](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1112742).

To set the firewall zone for an interface in this circumstance, be sure to add it to, e.g., `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eno1`.

```
ZONE="external"
```